# Python Argparse with Different Help Options

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program that has a bunch of parameters with default values.  Most people will want to run this program with the default values, but a few advanced users will want to tweak some of the other parameters.

Because there are so many parameters, the help screen takes up more than the entire terminal, making it difficult for basic users to figure out what exactly they should do.  However, I still want the advanced options to be available for the people who need them.  Is there a way to do both a short and a long version of --help?  For instance:

```
$ myprog.py --help
(Outputs help with only basic args)
```

and then

```
$ myprog.py --help=all
(Outputs help with all args)
```

Comment: Look at the `ArgumentParser.format_help` method in the `argparse.py` file.  This is the one that sets up a `HelpFormatter`.  I can imagine writing your own variation(s) that displays certain Argument Groups.  The code's well organized in terms of classes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any support from this built into argparse. You will most likely need to build it yourself. Here are a few tools provided by argparse that may help:

1. `ArgumentParser` has a `print_help()` method. You can call this when you want the full help. You might also be able to override it to show condensed help for less advanced users.
2. Implement your own [help action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action).